# is there thin cystoscope, thin to make less harm, used only for watching?

Tags: urology

once i come to urologist, he wanted to use cystoscope, and it was very thick, nearly 1 cm in diameter.

it was a tube, multifunctional, allowing to pass different instruments via it.

is there thin cystoscope, used in medicine widely, thin to make less harm, used only for watching?